# Best way to weed out weaker phones downloading app

Tags: android, performance, manifest

I have a game that requires a reasonably powerful processor, memory, perhaps even resolution eg 480x320 would not work well for this kind of game, etc. I have a few people getting crashes and giving low ratings because of this requirement. How can I weed out the weaker devices via Google Play?

Perhaps weed out the smallest screens as these are usually budget phones?

```
<supports-screens 
android:smallScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Or perhaps we can use something like

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="?"
```

But I would want sp and not DP?

Answer (score 0):

besides targeting by size, you can also start by excluding older phones (i.e. select phones above certain APIs only).

after narrowing down your devices, you can then manually select the phones you want using the Google Console. A presume that there are only so many phones with a powerful processor.

for my case i am using API 10+ which contains 10k devices. it'll be a lot less further filtering to do if you target API 21+

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could do this and also use the Google Play filters, like the <uses-feature> and <uses-configuration> tags: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html